# After installing 'magrittr',and loading the library it shows no function "%>% when executed

Tags: r

EDITED question to satisfy "good question". Although this was closed, not sure if editing this will help restore my capability in asking question since it was closed.

I've installed the "magrittr" package and still not executing even on a simple code block:
Appreciate any help, not sure if I'm missing something. Thanks.

```
x <- rnorm(10)
x
x %>% max
```

OUTPUT:

```
> x <- rnorm(10)
> x
 [1]  1.28100758  0.67208671  0.13992395  1.94236059 -1.60992115  0.39800788 -0.53785422  0.11119248  0.16196957 -0.07331401
> x %>% max
Error in x %>% max : could not find function "%>%"
```

Comment: Does your code include `library(magrittr)` or another package that loads it?

Comment: I did ran it in the beginning. The previous error message shows something like package is "corrupt" so I have to remove the package and reinstalled it. Performed the steps again including the library(magrittr). It works now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to load a library after installing it. Try:

```
library(magrittr)
```

Comment: I did ran it in the beginning. The previous error message shows something like package is "corrupt" so I have to remove the package and reinstalled it. Performed the steps again including the library(magrittr). It works now. Thanks